# Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

Im trying to host my project on github pages, project is working good in localhost but on gh pages I got blank page and an error like this on console:

> Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature
> not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the error message, it's because i'm using react router, so i need to define the routes according to github repo name

Before:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

After:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/desa" element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this is issue use the "exact" in routes

```
return <BrowserRouter>
<div className="App">
<Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
    <Route exact path="startcreating" element={ <Start /> } />
    <Route exact path="aboutus" element={ <About /> } />
    {/* <Route path="signup" element={ <SignUpModel /> } /> */}
</Routes> 
</div>
</BrowserRouter>;
```

Comment: For anyone else that is looking I ran into a problem using `basename` within my `<HashRouter>`, apparently they don't work well together