# Permission Policy Header, Origin trial feature not enabled: browsing-topics

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, undocumented-behavior

I've been working on a site in SvelteKit and noticed this new warn.

`Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'browsing-topics'.`

I have never seen this in my life, so I googled it and found absolutely no documented cases of this happening before, thus my post here.

I've checked on sites by going onto them & refreshing, and this error shows up on almost every single site I tried it own. This suggests to me it's really new. My best guess it's something related to [KOSA](https://www.stopkosa.com/), but I wanted to ask if anyone knew more than me about this.

I am running the latest release version of Google Chrome, if anyone was wondering.

Comment: The error message mentions the [`Permissions-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Permissions_Policy) header; have you looked for that in the response headers?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry No, I'm out at the minute but I'll give it a look once I get home.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72948207/error-with-permissions-policy-header-origin-trial-controlled-feature-not-enable